# running linux c++ code in windows

Tags: c++, windows, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ Portability between Windows and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261608/c-portability-between-windows-and-linux)

i am new to c++ programming and i dont really know much about it

i am running linux (ubuntu) in my desktop and my laptop is running windows but it has charger problems.. anyway, what i want to do is to program softwares in linux and run them in my laptop (windows)... so my question is is there any difference between programming c++ in linux and windows and if the generated program only runs on linux, can i re-compile the code that has been compiled and ran fine in linux??

i have looked in google but i didnt really get useful informations!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ code can be compiled quite happily on Linux, Windows and a gazillion other platforms. Where you will have problems is with the libraries that you link to. So long as you stick to the standard library of C++ or highly portable libraries like boost then you should have relatively few issues. If you link to a library that is only available on one of the platforms, then you will hit trouble.

Comment: awesome!! thank you very very much!!!

i gues i wont use any non standard library

Comment: @Awah: You don't need to limit yourself to the standard library.  You just have to limit yourself to libraries which are compatible with the platforms which you wish to support, and there are plenty of those.  [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) comes to mind as one of the most popular.

Comment: As long as a library says it's cross-platform it should compile and work fine on all the platforms the library says it supports